# Dynamic loading vs. dynamic linking?

Tags: memory-allocation, memory-access

What is the difference between dynamic loading and dynamic linking?

Both systems seem to allow shared libraries, but I am struggling to differentiate between them.

Comment: Although it is very late to put in any answer to question, but I found a very good explanation of this on quora. Following is the link for anybody's reference who has the same question. https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-exact-difference-between-dynamic-loading-and-dynamic-linking

Answer (score 3):

Dynamic linking is performed at the time of program loading only and uses compile-time established names.  Dynamic loading can be done at any point in program execution.

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading):

> Unlike static linking and loadtime linking, this mechanism allows a computer program to startup in the absence of these libraries, to discover available libraries, and to potentially gain additional functionality.